# Is that possible to call native keypress and mouse move from Chrome App/Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, dom-events, javascript-engine

Like java.awt.Robot or RobotJS does.

Once again, I need actually move mouse and hit keys from Chrome app/extension (not just plain web site, know that's impossible)?

Comment: impossible as I think